# Why friction is absent when normal force is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

When an object is placed in an inclined plane (rough), and the inclination is made to 90 degrees with horizontal. In this case normal contact force is zero, implying that frictional force is zero. But even in this case, intermolecular force and resistance due to roughness on surface is still present . Then why we say friction is absent here?

Answer (score 2):

It is an empirical law (based on experimental observations) that the force due to friction is directly proportional to the applied load. This is known as Amonton’s First Law. So when the applied load is zero, then the force due to friction is zero.

If you disagree with this law then you will need to provide experimental evidence to show that it is incorrect.

Comment: It is an approximation, not a fundamental law in any way, not guaranteed to be valid in extreme cases like near zero.

Comment: @Pieter Agreed. But if the questioner believes they have a more accurate approximation in which friction at zero load is not zero then they still need to provide experimental evidence to support their case. Just saying “I don’t believe this” is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

When the incline is made 90 degrees with the horizontal, the component of the force due to the gravitational field on the body kept on the incline has a zero horizontal component. Hence, the normal/contact force is zero. Therefore, frictional force is zero.

Comment: do you mean that normal force depends on gravitational field ??

Comment: there's no other force in the problem the OP presented other than gravity. so yes. if you were to hold the block against the incline wall then that would supply the normal force.

Comment: you should check out for the questions on the cause of normal force first on this site.

Comment: It doesn't supply normal force. The external force would just bring the molecules closer .

Comment: what are u even saying? is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @Ankit Pressing the block against the wall would mean a normal force on both sides of the block.

Comment: @Adrian Howard the force indicated in the figure as F is the **normal force** acting on the body by the hand and this is the force about which you are talking.

Comment: @Ankit but why would you introduce a new force that was not mentioned in the question? The question involved a block, an incline and gravity.

Comment: @Debasis_Buxy it was just an example to begin with. The second para tells about the original scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you press a body against the wall with some force **F** then the surface of the body and the wall are close enough and hence both experience a Normal force ( which depends on electromagnetic forces and Pauli exclusion principle) and in that case friction force is also present since the body tend to fall due to gravity.

[image]

But when you remove the external force there is no force on the body to counterbalance the electromagnetic forces by the wall and to some extent the **so called contact** breaks . Since there is no contact then friction force is also absent because it depends upon relative motion of the two surfaces in contact.

Comment: What about roughness?

Comment: @GRAVITON PI let me ask you what is roughness ?? And about whose roughness are you talking ??

Comment: Surface is not smooth that provides  friction too right?

Comment: @GRAVITON PI what is surface then ?? Please cooperate with me for sometime.

Comment: @GRAVITON PI Surface is defined as a particular arrangement of molecules. So talking about its roughness is just a macroscopic version of the microscopic intermolecular forces.

Comment: Then what is providing normal in case of a chalk dust sliding on black board?

Comment: @GRAVITON PI     Can we discuss this in chat ?

Comment: What chat? I don't know

Comment: @GRAVITON PI kindly go to chat room and search for Ankit and GRAVITON PI room and let's discuss their.

Answer (score 1):

> ...In this case normal contact force is zero, implying that frictional force is zero.

Yes, that's *by definition*. [Friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) is defined as being proportional to the normal force between two surfaces.

> But even in this case, intermolecular force and resistance due to roughness on surface is still present.

Yes, there are phenomena that could oppose a sliding motion between two surfaces even when there is no normal force between them, but those are given other names. (e.g., "[Adhesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesion).")